# How to have “My Cart” in banner7.phtml? how to show everything same like in header My cart

Tags: php, magento

i have installed magento 1.8.1 and i want to show My Cart right after banner section. i am placing the code in banner.phtml file and it seems working but problem is that it is not showing cart items and cost etc stuff.
can any one please share some universal code that can be used anywhere in .phtml file.
my source code is below:

```
<div class="slider-mycart">
<div class="block block-verticalmenu">
<div>
    <div class="block-cart">
        <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
        <!--<span class="top-cart-icon"></span>-->
        <span>
            <!--<span>Shopping Cart</span><br/>-->
            <?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?></span>
        <div class="top-cart-content">
            <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
            <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
                <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
                <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions') ?>
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as "universal code"

Comment: ok so how do i resolve this issue?